# how to make infinity value flag o in np.where

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

In my dataframe i want to add one more column flag , normally can do this with `np.where()`, but here is one problem , when condition value is infinity i give flag 1 but i want if infinity always give zero .how to make it possible to give infinity flag zero

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'x1':[4],'x2':[0]})

df['flag']=np.where(df['x1']/df['x2']>0.20,1,0)
```

normally when `x2` value is not zero its work fine , but when there is infinity its flag is always 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain mask by [`numpy.isinf`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isinf.html):

```
s = df['x1']/df['x2']
df['flag']=np.where((s>0.20) & ~np.isinf(s),1,0)
print (df)
   x1  x2  flag
0   4   0     0
```

Or:

```
s = df['x1']/df['x2']
df['flag']=np.where((s<=0.20) | np.isinf(s),0, 1)
print (df)
   x1  x2  flag
0   4   0     0
```